# Sequelize invalid value Symbol(ne)

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I have the following two files running on an Express Node.js server:

home.js

```
var express = require('express')
var sequelize = require('sequelize')
var db = require('../../shared/db.js')

var op = sequelize.Op

var router = express.Router()

router.get('/home', function(req, res, next) {
    db.shared.person.findAll({
        where: {
            email: {
                [op.ne]: null
            }
        },
        order: ['id']
    }).then(function (person) {
        res.locals = {
            person: person
        }
        res.render('home')
    })
})

module.exports = router
```

db.js

```
var sequelize = require('sequelize')

var config = {
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 5432,
  username: '...',
  password: '...',
  database: 'postgres',
  dialect: 'postgres',
  operatorsAliases: false
}
var db = new sequelize(config)

module.exports = {
  shared: {
    person: db.define('person', {
      id: {
        type: sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true
      },
      name: sequelize.STRING,
      email: sequelize.INTEGER
    }, { freezeTableName: true , timestamps: false, schema: 'shared' }),
  }
}
```

When I try to run this query, I get an error claiming `Unhandled rejection Error: Invalid value { [Symbol(ne)]: null }`

What am I doing wrong? I can use `$ne` and even `ne` just fine but they've been deprecated and are not entirely safe to use. Furthermore, it's not just `[op.ne]` - I get this error when I use any conditional like this.

I'm basing this all on this [guide](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html) so I'm not really sure what I could be doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequelize instance in both `db.js` and `home.js` are different, this is because node caches a required module based on it path.

To solve this issue you can pass around correct instance in `db.js`

```
module.exports = {
  shared: {
    person: db.define('person', {
      id: {
        type: sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true
      },
      name: sequelize.STRING,
      email: sequelize.INTEGER
    }, { freezeTableName: true , timestamps: false, schema: 'shared' }),
  },
  db: db
}
```

Then finally use operators from that shared instance to do query

```
var express = require('express')
var sequelize = require('sequelize')
var db = require('../../shared/db.js')

var op = db.db.Op;

var router = express.Router()

router.get('/home', function(req, res, next) {
    db.shared.person.findAll({
        where: {
            email: {
                [op.ne]: null
            }
        },
        order: ['id']
    }).then(function (person) {
        res.locals = {
            person: person
        }
        res.render('home')
    })
})

module.exports = router
```

One more thing, string operators are completely safe to use if you properly sanitize your user inputs. You only need to use secure operators if you are passing un-sanitized user input to Sequelize methods.

More on this topic

- http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#operators-security
- https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/8417

Comment: This was super helpful, thank you very much! One question though: how do I sanitise user inputs with Node.js/Express?

Answer (score 7):

`Unhandled rejection Error: Invalid value` might also appear if you didn't setup string aliases like this:

```js
const Op = Sequelize.Op;
const operatorsAliases = {
  $eq: Op.eq,
  $ne: Op.ne,
  ...
  $any: Op.any,
  $all: Op.all,
  $values: Op.values,
  $col: Op.col
};

const connection = new Sequelize(db, user, pass, { operatorsAliases });
```

But, better to remove String based aliases from code and use [Op.ne] for example, Sequlize is planning to deprecate them soon.