# Error: Invalid value { username: { '$eq': 'admin' } } by sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, authentication, sequelize.js, logical-operators

I'm trying to make a login router for the back end where the user  can both login using his email or his username. To do this the code tries to find or the username or the email in the database. but when I run the code and send json data to the login router I get the following error:

```
throw new Error(`Invalid value ${logger.inspect(val)}`);
          ^

Error: Invalid value { username: { '$eq': 'admin' } }
    at Object.escape (D:\programmeerstuff\javascript\pws\version 0.0.1\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sql-string.js:53:11)
    at MySQLQueryGenerator.escape (D:\programmeerstuff\javascript\pws\version 0.0.1\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-generator.js:763:22)
    at D:\programmeerstuff\javascript\pws\version 0.0.1\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-generator.js:1989:71
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at MySQLQueryGenerator._whereParseSingleValueObject (D:\programmeerstuff\javascript\pws\version 0.0.1\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-generator.js:1989:52)
    at MySQLQueryGenerator.whereItemQuery (D:\programmeerstuff\javascript\pws\version 0.0.1\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-generator.js:1805:19)
    at D:\programmeerstuff\javascript\pws\version 0.0.1\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-generator.js:1730:25
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at MySQLQueryGenerator.whereItemsQuery (D:\programmeerstuff\javascript\pws\version 0.0.1\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-generator.js:1728:35)
    at MySQLQueryGenerator.getWhereConditions (D:\programmeerstuff\javascript\pws\version 0.0.1\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-generator.js:2071:19)

Node.js v18.12.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

here is the user.js code:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { Users } = require("../models");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;
  console.log(req.body);
  console.log(username);

  const user = await Users.findAll({
    where: {
      $or: [
        {
          username: {
            $eq: username
          }
        },
        {
          email:{
            $eq: username
          }
        }
      ]
    },
  });
  if (!user) {
    res.json({ error: "password or username incorrect" });
  }

  bcrypt.compare(password, user.password).then((match) => {
    if (!match) res.json({ error: "password or username incorrect" });
  });
});
```

the database index.js:

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
const db = {};
const Op = Sequelize.Op;
const operatorsAliases = {
  $eq: Op.eq,
  $ne: Op.ne,
  $any: Op.any,
  $all: Op.all,
  $values: Op.values,
  $col: Op.col
};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config, { operatorsAliases });
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config, { operatorsAliases });
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

I treid to use the awnser from this question: [Sequelize invalid value Symbol(ne)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47379702/sequelize-invalid-value-symbolne) but I got the same error as above.

Comment: how about just where: { $or: [ { username }, { email:username } ] },

Comment: got the same error

Comment: What the error now ? we are not using `eq`

Comment: throw new Error(`Invalid value ${logger.inspect(val)}`);
          ^

Error: Invalid value { username: 'admin' }

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case, I was passing a variable of the wrong type.
You need to check:

1. does the column name in your table match
2. make sure you pass the variable with the correct data type (compare with the type from the database)

Comment: thanks for the reaction!!, I checked both the names and the type and they both match, and when I do it without the or gate it works